# Difference between two ways of making this <ul> list?

Tags: html, list, html-lists

Is there any difference between structuring a list in both of these ways? They both look the same in browser but is there a difference functionally?

Note: The difference is the "Types of sugar" list item and how it's structured.

```
<ul>
<li>Milk</li>
<li>Bread</li>
<li>Types of sugar:</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Brown sugar</li>
    <li>White sugar</li>
  </ul>
<li>Water</li>  
</ul>


<ul>
<li>Milk</li>
<li>Bread</li>
<li>
  <ul>Types of sugar:
    <li>Brown sugar</li>
    <li>White sugar</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>Water</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first way is technically incorrect.  a ul can not be the child of a ul